# Restrict IP addresses to access your application on GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an application on GAE . Suppose I want that application to available on to 172.12.*.* IP addresses . How can i do that ?

Comment: it's your app. If you want to restrict usage to a specific set of IP's then check the IP of the user before allowing them access!

Comment: you mean to check it in my code ? can i restrict it on app engine level like we give access of cloud sql by providing access control to that ip addres.

Comment: yes, but you have to write that code, there is no feature like you are talking about for SQL

Comment: 172 is a private range. You'll have to restrict access to the external facing IP of your organisation.

Comment: yeah this is a private range. But suppose I want to restrict 1.14.*.* ip address .

Comment: GAE won't care what particular private range you are on as it won't see any of that. It'll only see the external IP of your network. You might want to consider using authentication or similar instead of such an IP restriction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ip = self.request.remote_addr

if ip in allowed_ip_list:
    allow_access = True
else:
    allow_access = False
```

More detailed answer here: [Get IP address in Google App Engine + Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231077/get-ip-address-in-google-app-engine-python)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old post, but for ref: here's the clean way of blocking IPs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/dos?csw=1

EDIT: to complete the answer, in python all you need to do is create a `dos.yaml` file in the root directory of your application, and add the ip or ip groups you want to deny service to:

`blacklist:
- subnet: 192.0.2.1
  description: A single IPv4 address
- subnet: abcd::123:4567
  description: A single IPv6 address`

Then make sure to upload your new entries by running `appcfg.py update_dos <directory>`