# How to allow access to App Engine from only specified IPs?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication

I am building a simple POST handler on GAE in Python that will accept a POST and write it to a Cloud SQL database.

I would like to limit access to this app to a limited number of IPs - non-GAE webservers where the POST originates. **Essentially, how to allow POSTS from my IPs and disallow all other traffic?**

Seems like a simple and common operation, but I haven't found a solution online that seems to fit.  Most GAE authentication and routing packages are built around user auth.

Where should I look for a solution here? What Google keywords should I be using?  Is this going to be written into the app itself or should I be focused on another component of GCP for IP access and routing?

Thanks!

Comment: How big is this range of IPs? Is it something you can store and perform a simple check for at the time of connection?

Comment: Very small. At first it will only be one or two.  And yes, store and check is what I envisioned.

Comment: In that case, since it's only a few IPs, maybe a firewall rule is a better option here?

Comment: Are firewall rules available with Apps Engine, or is this a Compute Engine feature?  https://cloud.google.com/docs/permissions-overview?hl=en#h.6ve8js2j7vwq

Comment: you can check remote_addr in the request, try self.request.remote_addr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231077/get-ip-address-in-google-app-engine-python and just check if it's in your allowed list before proceeding with the POST.

Comment: It looks like you're also able to restrict access by IP to apps. Relevant links: https://support.google.com/a/answer/6047998?hl=en and https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/access-control

Comment: @PaulCollingwood THAT looks promising. Post as an answer and I'll likely accept it.

Comment: @tsujin, I'm aware of the Cloud SQL access controls and I'm using them, actually. They're slick. ...and I don't want to confuse _Google Apps Engine_ with _Google Apps_. (Looks like the support article might apply to the latter.) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All credit to [Paul Collingwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1351600/paul-collingwood) for alerting me to the existence of request.remote_addr.

Here is my solution as of now:

```
ALLOWED_IP = ['173.47.xx.xx1', '173.47.xx.xx2']

class PostHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def post(self):

    # Read the IP of the incoming request
    ip = self.request.remote_addr

    # If the IP is allowed, execute our code
    if ip in ALLOWED_IP:
        # Execute some awesome code

    # Otherwise, slam the door!
    else:
        self.error(403)
```

I'm not entirely sure that my `self.error()` usage is appropriate here, but this is working! POST requests made from the allowed IPs are accepted and executed.  All others are given a 403.

I'm always eager to hear improvement suggestions.

Comment: This is a nice way to do what you want, indeed. Another solution would be to use Managed VMs, where you can configure firewall rules like in Compute Engine. Cheers!

Comment: How can you configure firewall rules with MVM?